# Error to compile Xcode Swift project using C++ library linked on Build Phases

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, g++, objective-c-swift-bridge

I've searched a lot on the web but not found the solution for my problem.
My objective is create a simple class in C++ and use it on Swift. To this I did follows this tutorial -> http://www.swiftprogrammer.info/swift_call_cpp.html (It's very nice).
Basically I've followed the steps:

1. Create `junk.cpp` and `junk.h` files
2. Compile using `g++ or/and clang++`
3. Create .a file with: `$ ar r libjunkcpp.a junk.o`
4. Linked to Xcode in `Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> Add`

So when I did this the Xcode not compiles more my project, on the left side of Xcode appears the error message:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And on the log the error's message is:

> ld: archive has no table of contents file
>   '/Users/augustosansoncadini/Documents/XcodeProjects/Ex_cpp_Swift_CmdLineTool/junk/libjunkcpp.a'
>   for architecture x86_64

I think that need compile to it architecture but when I type `g++ -v` the result is:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

So I conclude that the architecture target is correct.

I think that this image can help:

[image]

**Note:** 
When I remove `.a` file from Link Binary With Libraries the code compiles fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you miss is a call to the [`ranlib`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/ranlib/) command to generate the table of contents:

```
$ ranlib libjunkcpp.a
```

The [`ar`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/ar/) and `ranlib` commands must always be paired.

Comment: This return warning message: `warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: warning for library: libjunkcpp.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)`. And the other error occurs on my .h files: https://imgur.com/a/ysH9dDH

Comment: @Augusto For the new error (which is unrelated to the problem you ask about) see [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I will make another question.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem by the end of the same tutorial at http://www.swiftprogrammer.info/swift_call_cpp.html.

But the error I got when building the project was:

```
ld: library not found for -ljunkcpp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

No idea where the "ljunkcpp" naming (vs "**lib**junkcpp") suddenly came from, but what I did to solve it was:

1. Removed `libjunkcpp.a` altogether.
2. Compiled with `g++ -c junk.cpp` again.
3. Ran `ar r hellocpp.a junk.o` again (notice the different `hellocpp.a` filename).
4. Removed the old Build Phase Link to `libjunkcpp.a`.
5. Linked `hellocpp.a` instead in *Link Binary With Libraries*. Rebuilt and ran.

```
Hello, World!
The integer from C++ is 1234
```

Must have been some name collision. Hope this helps someone.